# Angularjs javascript loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following AngularJS controller get id parameter from html page ,then the controller should load file1.js or file2.js depending on this id ,the files loaded but didn't executed in html page

```
    myappApp.controller('ChartConfigController', function ($scope, ChartConfigService) {
    $scope.findOne= function() {
     ChartConfigService.findOne($scope.id).then(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj.type);
            var x = obj.type;
            if (x=="pie") {
                $.getScript("file1.js", function(){
                       console.log("File 1 loaded");
                    });
            } else if (x=="line") {
                $.getScript("file2.js", function(){
                       console.log("File 2 loaded");
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("not found");
            }

        });
    };      
  });
```

html page

```
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; 
      margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

file1.js and file2.js contain highchart code like this,It loaded but didn't execute,I don't know why.

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A self-invoking anonymous runs automatically/immediately when you create it and has no name, hence called anonymous. Here is the format of self-executing anonymous function:

```
(function(){
 // some code…
})();
```

So in order to get your function to run you should correct your syntax in the file1.js and file2.js files.:

```
(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
      ...

 })();
```

Comment: user3063182 yes the file loaded but highchart didn't appear in result page.

Comment: I tried this code many times It works sometimes and sometimes not work

Comment: If your file loads so Angularjs javascript loading issue is resolved, and you should mark it. If highchart isn't working, that's a different issue.